# Unity3d - Overwrite Debug.Log()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In JavaScript you are able to overwrite a function e.g. `console.log()` like this:

```js
console.log("test1");

console.log = function() { return; };

console.log("test2");
```

I often used this to hide all debug console messages.
I tried to apply this in C# at Unitys `Debug.Log()` like this:

```
Debug.Log = () => { return; };
```

But I get `Cannot assign to Log, because it is a message group` and `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer`.

Is it possible to overwrite it somehow?
Im just curious.

Comment: I think that's just one of those cool javascript things you can do. This should help with what you need though: Debug.logger.logEnabled = false;

Comment: Why do you want to override it? What's the reason?

Comment: @Programmer, I was just curious if this is possible just like in javascript. Im new to C#.

Comment: Nope. You can't do that unless your script inherits from the `Debug` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply disable the logger in a sane way

```
Debug.unityLogger.logEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the default logger handler

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class LogHandler : ILogHandler
{
    public bool enable;
    private static ILogHandler unityLogHandler = Debug.unityLogger.logHandler;

    public LogHandler(bool enable = true)
    {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public void LogException(Exception exception, UnityEngine.Object context)
    {
        if(enable)
        {
            unityLogHandler.LogException(exception, context);
        }
    }

    public void LogFormat(LogType logType, UnityEngine.Object context, string format, params object[] args)
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR || DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
        if(enable)
        {
            unityLogHandler.LogFormat(logType, context, format, args);
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Using:

```
Debug.unityLogger.logHandler = new LogHandler(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but does this mean I can make the logger dump certain Debug.LogError(...) to a file, while it's still being output to the console?